# Can we write custom Spring transaction manager?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Suppose that we have a `businessLogic()` method that does 2 things: write some information in a local cache and save the same information in the DB using `JDBC` so that the contents of the cache and the DB are always the same.

I know we can use Spring's `JDBC` Datasource Transaction Manager to automatically rollback the DB in case of exception. However, how can we define a custom transaction manager that also rollbacks the content of the cache in this case, so that the contents of the cache and the DB are always in sync?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Gab's answer is right, except for the parts that aren't.

XA is indeed the standard way to coordinate update of multiple resources... except that where the cache is local i.e. in-process, it's not necessarily a resource.

A cache doesn't exactly 'implement JTA', it acts in one of two roles in the XA protocol, according to how it's deployed. It can be an XAResource, but that's usually only required where its lifecycle is distinct from that of the client process. For in-process use, it's more likely to be a Synchronization.

The key difference between these roles is: XAResource is fault-tolerant, but Synchronization is not. For a volatile cache that's in-memory with the client process, it's sufficient to rebuild the cache after a crash by querying the db. For a cache that's out of process, a client crash after the db tx commit but before the cache update would leave the cache out of sync, at least until it expired or was manually refreshed.

Depending on the cache implementation, there is no guarantee it will pick the right mode automatically. See the configuration reference for your chosen implementation e.g. https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#tx_sync_enlist

Spring isn't actually a JTA XA transaction manager either, though it does provide an abstraction layer over them. It's possible to use Spring to drive a database in non-XA mode, but then you have no standard hook for the cache Synchronizations and you need a proprietary interface instead. Or you can have the database do pseudo-XA via a one-phase resource adapter. Full-on 2PC is probably overkill for your use case.

Comment: very instructive answer :) not very clear however, at least for me. Probably we don't have the same idea of what is a local cache. Hibernate N2 is local cache IMHO but as it's shared between multiple threads it does not fit your definition. Regarding LLRTO, only one of the resource can avoid the 2PC so either the cache or the database must be xa. Not sure I got your last sentence regarding this. Could you please tell me what exactly is wrong in my answer ?

Comment: ehcache is clearly intended to work also with "spring TransactionManager" and auto register against it : https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe that the task of transaction management for cache is redundant. I advice you to only update the cache if database level transaction is successfully committed.

Most scenarios with cache using are completely acceptable if you have small window between updates of entity in database and its cached state.

If your case rejects any possibility of outdated cache then you probably have to avoid using cache or use something special for caching, probably the same database as your original data supporting transactions. Otherwise you **will** have problems trying to maintain consistency between two different systems: db level and cache level. Most of the time the best you can achieve is eventual consistency - it means that anyway you will have windows of inconsistent state and only then (eventually) the data will become consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to deal with transaction distributed among multiple resources is to use [XA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA)

You must then access your database using an xa-datasource and use a cache implementation implementing [JTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API), eg. [ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/xa.html).

I'am not very familiar with spring boot, but the transaction manager should manage the transaction synchronization across both resources out of the box with the appropriate configuration (no need to override anything)